# FlatList not working on using react-native-image-header-scroll-view React Native

Tags: react-native

I use react-native-image-header-scroll-view but renderHeader to display the image but after using it it seems that FlastList is not working

here is my code

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  ImageHeaderScrollView,
  TriggeringView,
} from 'react-native-image-header-scroll-view';
const MAX_HEIGHT = 400;
const MIN_HEIGHT = Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 90 : 55;
const ProductDetailScreen = ({route}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{backgroundColor: colors.bodyColor, flex: 1}}>
      <ImageHeaderScrollView
        maxHeight={MAX_HEIGHT}
        minHeight={MIN_HEIGHT}
        renderHeader={() => (
          <ProductDetailImage route={route} />
        )}></ImageHeaderScrollView>

    </View>
  );
};

export default ProductDetailScreen;
```

ProductDetailImage

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const ProductDetailImage = ({route}) => {
  const {product} = route.params;
  const [currentSate, setCurrentState] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef();
  const updateCurrentState = e => {
    const contentOffsetX = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const currentSate = Math.round(contentOffsetX / windowWidth);
    setCurrentState(currentSate);
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
      }}>
      <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        ref={ref}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={updateCurrentState}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        decelerationRate="fast"
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={product.image}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
            <View key={index}>
              <Image
                source={{uri: item}}
                style={{width: windowWidth, height: 400}}
              />
            </View>
          );
        }}
      ...
  );
};

export default ProductDetailImage;
```

I want the renderHeader to be able to scroll the image

if I remove the ProductDetailImage from the renderHeader everything works fine again